# Is it possible to hide icons on the dock of apps that are running on other spaces?

Tags: dock, application-switcher, macos, spaces

I was wondering if it is possible to hide icons on the dock of apps that are running on other spaces. Also I would like the app-switcher to show only the apps that are working on the current desktop I'm using.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try looking around for third party applications. I don't think it is possible to do this normally.

Comment: Neither of the things you are asking for are possible, at least not without a deep system-level hack.

Comment: it's *possible* that Witch from Many Tricks can do something like this (but I haven't used it in years so I don't recall)